# How to use the copy constructor with pointer member fields?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Would this be a decent solution to solve the copy constructor issue when using pointers and when copying an object.

```
Person(const Person& source) {
    if (source.agePtr != nullptr) {
        agePtr = new int(*source.agePtr);
    }
}
```

I just want to make sure that how I am dealing with the pointer not copying the previous object address is the right way. It definitely solves the problem but I just want to know from other people who are more experienced in C++ if the way I am approaching it is correct and good practice. I come from C# so this kind of stuff is very new to me.

```
Person person1{ 91 };
Person person2{ person1 };
std::cout << "Person2 before person1 change: " << person2.GetAgePtr()<< "\n";
person1.ChangePtr(1);  // change fist object
std::cout << "Person2 After person1 change: " << person2.GetAgePtr()<< "\n";
```

Comment: The most straightforward solution would be not to use raw pointers at all.

Comment: If you ask how to test if a copy constructor is coping an object, so yes. you change the source and check the copy won't be changed.

Comment: Please clarify whether you really need a pointer or if an int would be enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's about how you would do it.

I don't know when the last time I stored a pointer to an int, but you're just using it as an example (I hope). However, under modern C++, you can begin to get rid of virtually all raw pointers and move to smart pointers instead:

```
#include <memory>

class Person {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<MyOtherObject> myOtherObject;
    ...
};
```

You make a shared pointer like this:

```
myOtherObject = std::make_shared<MyOtherObject();
```

You can add arguments to it if there's a corresponding constructor.

You use these just like pointers, but when you're done, you don't have to free them. They are smart pointers. They work like magic.

Just be careful about circular references.

Comment: Thank you. And yes it was just a quick example. And I've heard of smart pointers but ill defiantly look into it. I've been using c++ for a few days now so much stuff to learn. But thank you again for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

How you do it is the way to go if you really need to work with raw pointers. You could optimize your code using member list initialization and the ternary operator (`condition? true statement : false statement`):

```
Person(const Person& p)
: agePtr(p.agePtr!=nullptr? new int(*p.agePtr) : nullptr) 
{}
```

However, when working with raw pointers, don't forget to delete `agePtr` otherwise you leak memory. Therefore, you should consider using smart pointers e.g. `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yeah, I delete it through the destructor. And the smart pointers part definitely will look into. And thank you for the tip on the member initialization part.